# Use Open API 3 Codegen for Spring Boot 2 client and server stubs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

**TL;DR** How can I use OpenApi3 Codegen to generate code for `spring-web >= 5.x` using the rest template?

I have been using the OpenApi 3 code generator for creation of spring-mvc server stubs and spring rest template clients to be used in other applications.

Now I am upgrading my applications to Spring Boot 2 and I was astonished, that I can not find anything on how to configure the maven generator plugin to create code for a spring boot 2 codebase or strictly speaking to use a `spring-web` dependency >= `5.0.0`, without using webflux and webclient, which would obviously be a major breaking change.
For the rest template it seems that only `spring-web 4.x` can be included.

Ignoring that fact and simply using the generated code in spring projects would most likely work without any issues, as it seems there are no breaking changes in any spring code used in the generated library, but nevertheless, it feels just wrong to depend on that and mix two different major versions of spring.

Is there any way to properly configure that or to run the generator in 'Spring 5 mode' while still using the rest template?

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new/choose so that the community can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`, see the example below. The plugin will generate client classes automatically before compiling of the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.ilysenko</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-v3-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>https://somehost.com/openapi/swagger-ui/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Generated API classes are the Spring components, so you can inject them in your application, in this case don't forget to scan the generated sources' package.

If it doesn't work, see my working example: https://github.com/0x100/tinka